# Micro sistema de classes em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

O que gostaria é inicializar automaticamente uma struct que recebe ponteiros de funções. Por exemplo:

```
struct teste{
    int x;
    int y;
    int (*soma)(int, int);
};

typedef struct teste Teste;

int soma(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

Teste *t1;
t1->soma = soma;

printf("---> 2 + 2 = %d \n", t1->soma(2, 2)); // ---> 2 + 2 = 4
```

Isso compila e executa muito bem. Porém, gostaria de não precisar fazer o:

```
Teste *t1;
t1->soma = soma;
```

E simplesmente fazer algo como:

```
Teste *t1;
*t1 = newTeste();
```

Ou até mesmo:

```
Teste *t1 = newTeste();
```

Sendo que a função `newTeste()` seria algo como:

```
Teste newTeste(){
    Teste *t;
    t->soma = soma;
    return *t;
}
```

Isso compila mas não roda.

Sei que estou me perdendo nos ponteiros, mas não consigo enxergar exatamente onde. Também não sei se o que quero fazer é algo viável, apenas me surgiu esta ideia de micro simular uma classe e gostaria de colocar em prática.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se está retornando um ponteiro o tipo da função deve ser um ponteiro, só falta isto.

```
Teste *newTeste() {
    Teste *t;
    t->soma = soma;
    return *t;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/PointerToMember.c).

Existe um outro problema, essa variável `soma` parece mágica, provavelmente deve ser global, não deveria fazer isto, especialmente quando quer simular uma classe.

Existem outros erros conceituais nessa construção.

Answer (score 0):

```
Teste newTeste(){
    Teste *t;
    t->soma = soma;
    return t;
}
```

Tente assim, sem o * no return.

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Acabei misturando um pouco das ideias apresentadas e cheguei ao seguinte código que atende ao que queria até o momento:

Declaração da "micro classe":

```
typedef struct teste{
    int x;
    int y;
    int (*soma)(int, int);
    int (*subtrai)(int, int);
    int (*divide)(int, int);
} Teste;

Teste newTeste(){
    int soma(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }

    int subtrai(int a, int b){
        return a - b;
    }

    int divide(int a, int b){
        return a / b;
    }

    Teste t;
    t.soma = soma;
    t.subtrai = subtrai;
    t.divide = divide;
    return t;
};
```

Utilização:

```
Teste t1 = newTeste();
t1.x = 12;
t1.y = 7;

Teste t2 = newTeste();
t2.x = 5;
t2.y = 5;

Teste t3 = newTeste();
t3.x = 4;
t3.y = 4;

// ---> 12 + 7 = 19
printf("---> %d + %d = %d \n", t1.x, t1.y, t1.soma(t1.x,t1.y)); 
// ---> 5 - 5 = 19
printf("---> %d - %d = %d \n", t2.x, t2.y, t2.subtrai(t2.x,t2.y)); 
// ---> 4 / 4 = 4
printf("---> %d / %d = %d \n", t3.x, t3.y, t3.divide(t3.x,t3.y));
```

Como sugerido, criei um escopo para a declaração dos "métodos"
Agora vou em busca de um "this".

Muito obrigado.